# Can't run the app on iPhone Simulator because of missing files

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've got a project with several cocoapods dependendencies. One of them is `OpenSSL-Universal`. It worked for a while until a couple of days ago.

I have `cocoapods 1.7.2` and `Xcode 10.2.1` and when I try to run the app on a Simulator, I get this error:

This app could not be installed at this time.

> Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/trevisil/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7362482B-3AF1-4419-A7FE-EB52AB22DCDC/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.QmfWcQ/extracted/Payload/Lifepots.app/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework

I've tried to:

1. Clean the build folder
2. Download the dependencies again
3. Use an older version of Cocoapods
4. Clean the DeriveData folder
5. Reboot the simulator
6. Reset the simulator
7. Reboot the laptop
8. Try from another laptop

**Any other suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

Now try to `pod deintegrate` and then `pod integrate`

1. Close **Xcode**
2. Open terminal, select **project directory** and type **command** `pod deintegrate`
3. After above process completed in **terminal** *type* `pod integrate` or  `pod install`
4. Reopen **Xcode** and `run` `project`

Comment: Also, make sure Xcode is closed when you do all this.

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh, I've just tried this and still no success unfortunetely.